# E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

Tags: sudo, samsung, chromebook

I don't know what caused the following to happen:

[image]

The content of `/etc/apt/sources-list.d/mono-xamarin.list` is `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources-list.d/mono-xamarin.list` on an [Ubuntu Paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post that here?

Comment: Looks like a broken file - `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` is malformed which causes problems.  Post the content either via the Ubuntu Pastebin, or as an edit to your question here.

Comment: Try the command and check whether the folder is having enough permissions, ls -ld /usr
ls -ld /usr/bin

Comment: I get this error when i type in sudo apt-get update into the terminal. E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: @ANewGuy4 delete the `sudo apt-get update` line from `/etc/apt/sources-list.d/mono-xamarin.list` file and then run `sudo apt-get autoremove` next run `sudo apt-get update`. Note that you have to close the synaptic package manager first.

Comment: @KasiyA I cant delete the apt-get update cause i dont have permission to write in that file.

Comment: yah i figured that was why that came up thanks KasiyA ityped it and it got rid of that file which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the `sudo apt-get update` line from your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` file.

```
sudo sed -i.bak '1d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that you have to close the synaptic package manager first.