# Type 'sudo' is not known in source list

Tags: apt

I'm a first time Linux user. My laptop wasn't connecting to the wifi so I followed the instructions from [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309072).

On typing `sudo apt-get update` after that, I got this error:

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is in line 2 of `/etc/apt/sources.list `?

Comment: [E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565803/e-type-sudo-is-not-known-on-line-1-in-source-list-etc-apt-sources-list-d-mon) might help.

Comment: It looks like you followed the instruction wrong.  Undo the changes in `/etc/apt/source.list` in the first step. Read the first step again. un-comment the `#deb.....` lines as instructed.  **Save the changes and exit the text editor!!!!** The second step must be entered in the `terminal`. By the way, these are instructions from 2009. Are you sure you need to do all these to get your WiFi working in 2015?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your prompt responses! You were right, I'd accidentally changed the file. I opened it in the file editor and removed the changes, and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you incorrectly added a source to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` on line 2.

Try opening up Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.

A regular source line will look similar to this:
 `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted`.

If it doesn't, then remove that line and try running `sudo apt-get update` again. If it works, we know that you added a source incorrectly and you can try following those instructions again.

---

What I'm assuming happened for you specifically is you added the line `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

What you should do if this is the case is remove that line entirely, and then uncomment all the source lines (delete all `#` characters from the beginning of a line.)

Then, you should save the file and exit out of `nano`.

Now, when you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` it should work and you can continue on following those instructions.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Thanks for writing out the answer. I will delete my comment to the question.